# unable to open file in file iterator class

Tags: c++, class

I have a task to create a file iterator. I try to open a file in class constructor like this:

```
int main () {
    FileIterator file("test_int.txt");//try to send a name of file to the class FileIterator

    return 0;
}
```

My class is:

```
class  FileIterator {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::ifstream file;
public:
    FileIterator(const std::string& name): name(name) {
    file.open(name);\\I think here is an error
}
    ~FileIterator(){
    file.close();
}
};
```

Compiler does not compile it and gives an error "no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream::open(const std::string&, const std::ios_base::openmode&)".
Please help. I just studing classes...

Comment: did you include `<fstream>` and `<string>` ?

Comment: You need to either activate C++11 mode in your compiler, or use `file.open(name.c_str())`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open

Comment: n.m - you was right)) I thought mingw supports C++11 already((

Comment: @user3402740 For backward compatibility reasons, C++11 is not enabled by default, you have to add -std=c++11 to CXXFLAGS.